# Multiple file upload using s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-go

I'd like to upload files to my s3 bucket via the aws golang sdk. I have a web server listening to POST requests and I'm expecting to receive multiple files of any type.

Using the sdk, the s3 struct `PutObjectInput` expects `Body` to be of type `io.ReadSeeker` and I'm not sure how to extract the content from the files uploaded and in turn satisfy the `io.ReadSeeker` interface.

```
images := r.MultipartForm.File

for _, files := range images {
    for _, f := range files {

        # In my handler, I can loop over the files
        # and see the content
        fmt.Println(f.Header)

        _, err = svc.PutObjectWithContext(ctx, &s3.PutObjectInput{
                Bucket: aws.String("bucket"),
                Key:    aws.String("key"),
                Body:   FILE_CONTENT_HERE,
            })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [FileHeader.Open](https://godoc.org/mime/multipart#FileHeader.Open) method to get an `io.ReadSeeker`.

```
    f, err := f.Open()
    if err != nil {
       // handle error
    }

    _, err = svc.PutObjectWithContext(ctx, &s3.PutObjectInput{
            Bucket: aws.String("bucket"),
            Key:    aws.String("key"),
            Body:   f,
        })
```

Open returns a [File](https://godoc.org/mime/multipart#File). This type satisfies the [io.ReadSeeker](https://godoc.org/io#ReadSeeker) interface.

Answer (score -2):

Use the S3 Manager's Uploader.Upload method, http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/s3/s3manager/#Uploader.Upload. We have an example at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/s3-example-basic-bucket-operations.html#s3-examples-bucket-ops-upload-file-to-bucket.